# If $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-3e^{-x}}{x}=9$ what is $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to find $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)$ given $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-3e^{-x}}{x}=9$.

The way I did the question was to do 
\begin{align*}
& \frac{\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x) - \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}3e^{-x}}{\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x}=9 \\
&\rightarrow \frac{\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x) - 3}{\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x}=9 \\
&\rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x) - 3=9\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x \\
&\rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x) - 3=9.0 \\
&\rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x) - 3=0 \\
&\rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=9
\end{align*}
which is the correct answer. However, I'm not sure if I'm allowed to multiply by $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x$ since it's equal to $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$
\lim_{x\to0} (f(x)-3e^{-x})
=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{f(x)-3e^{-x}}{x}\right)\times\lim_{x\to0}x
=9\times 0=0
$$
since both of  the limits in the product exist. Hence
$$
\lim_{x\to0} f(x)
=\lim_{x\to0} (f(x)-3e^{-x})+\lim_{x\to0} 3e^{-x}
=0+3
=3.
$$

Answer (score 1):

No, it is **not** valid to proceed as you did. In addition to multiplying both sides of an equation by zero, you also used

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x \to a} f(x)}{\lim_{x \to a} g(x)}$$

in a context where the denominator is zero. This is not a correct application of limit laws. The result of this is that you came up with an incorrect answer - the limit is $3$, not $9$.

---

To see why the limit is $3$, notice that the numerator $f(x) - 3e^{-x}$ *must* tend to zero for the limit to exist, since the denominator tends to zero. You can prove this by showing that

$$\left|\frac{f(x) - 3e^{-x}}{x}\right|$$

must be very large if $x$ is small and $f(x)$ is far from $3$.

Comment: I actually meant to write $3$ as my answer but I can see what you mean.